# What is the hole located below the 2nd or 3rd window of Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification

I see there is a hole located below the 2nd or 3rd window. What is its purpose?

[image]
(Sources: [flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rkc01/8155322207) and [planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net/photo/318139/ei-edz-transaero-airlines-boeing-737-8k5wl))

Comment: Thanks for editing! It's a kind of duplicate, but I haven't managed to find that answer and even if I had found it, I wouldn't have been able to match it with my question

Comment: You're welcome. I understand it's not always easy finding the related post, that's why I pointed it out. After pointing it out, did it answer the question? It's [happened before](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39433). Note that accepting the proposed duplicate does not delete your question. A duplicate is not a bad thing, your post can serve as a sign-post. Each plane has those static ports, so you can imagine the question repeating itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Static ports**. (capt & FO).

For sensing static (atmospheric) pressure ultimately used by various flight instruments (such as airspeed indicator, altimeter, etc.)

[image]
(Source: [b737.org.uk](http://www.b737.org.uk/probes.htm#staticports))